Where do I put the drawable resources in .NET Android at API level 35?
Up until API level 33, I used the automatically created drawable folder in the Resources folder to put my drawables into. Now when I create a new project in API level 35, the drawable folder is not getting created, and when I do it myself and copy the files into it, I get an error:
resource drawable/chatBackgroundLight (aka com.companyname.LocationConnection:drawable/chatBackgroundLight) not found.
The error occurs in the file named "chatBackgroundSelector.xml", which is located in the drawable folder, alongside with "chatBackgroundLight.xml" and "chatBackgroundDark.xml". Its content is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/chatBackgroundDark" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/chatBackgroundLight" />
</selector>

chatBackgroundLight.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/ContentDarkBackground" />
</shape>

The build action of all xml files are set automatically to AndroidResource.
How should I reference the files correctly?
